# How to suppress translation of months (or all fields) in receipts?

Tags: receipts, smarty, localisation, dates

My platform: CiviCRM 5.16.3 on Drupal 7.6.7 PHP 7.2 CentOS 7.
Drupal language is English.
CiviCRM l10n installed and selected my own languange zh_TW Chinese(Taiwan).

At receipt print-outs CiviCRM does all the translation it could, but I want the English version of dates e.g. Sep by %b, not my local language. (Because English dates are more universally understood.) In particular, how can I suppress translation at particular Smarty tag e.g. {$receive_date}?

If translation cannot be suppressed for some fields can I suppress translation for the whole printout?

I cannot find any trace of Month names translation in Drupal or CiviCRM localization files.

Thank you for your help.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to CiviCRM SE KLeeHK! I am not sure if you can suppress the translation of *particular* Smarty tags e.g. {$receive_date} or change the date format of only this occurence. The receipts can be edited under "System Workflow Message Template which you can find under "https://yoururl.com/civicrm/admin/messageTemplates?reset=1"

However, you can globally change your date formats under "https://yoururl.com/civicrm/admin/setting/date?reset=1".

I hope that helps.